# Jackson: Deserialize BigDecimal as plain String using annotation

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have this REST response:

```
{
    //more fields...
    prevValue: 10104401
}
```

And this POJO:

```
public class Parameter {

    //More fields...

    private String prevValue;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

I'm using Spring `RestTemplate` with `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. With response above, `prevValue` is deserialized as a `String` like `1.0104401E7`, in scientific notation.

I want it to be deserialized without scientific notation. Is there a way to do this using Jackson annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`@JsonFormat`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) annotation:

```java
public class Parameter {

    //More fields...

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private String prevValue;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jackson custom deserializer APIs to get the desired result.
See the sample below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Parameter p = om.readValue("{\"prevValue\": 101044012342343543}", Parameter.class);
        System.out.println(p.prevValue);
    }

    public static class Number2StringDesrializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            Number n = p.getNumberValue();
            return n.toString();
        }

    }

    public static class Parameter {

        @JsonDeserialize(using = Number2StringDesrializer.class)
        private String prevValue;

        public void setPrevValue(String prevValue) {
            this.prevValue = prevValue;
        }


        public String getPrevValue() {
            return prevValue;
        }
    }
}
```